# Reading specifc data from XML using MS Excel VB script

Tags: xml, vba, parsing

I am new to VB programing and I am trying to get mentioned below solution working

I have a site which gets refresh  at rate of 1 minute , data can be accessed as XML page  , I am trying to load XML file and parse to read a specific line and specific column and update to a sheet( only numeric value and times stamp in XML file change by time and structure , tag , constant remain consistent).

Requirement is to read data from each row "row refno="XX"" and Column 1, 5
my requirement is to read data very frequently thus looking for expert advise as well for optimise code from performance perspective.

I have developed code to execute subroutine every minute with stop/start control however facing difficulties in XML parsing.

1. Document is not getting loaded Error : Invalid at the top level of document
2. My intenation is to have a code to get single line by "row refno" and then get the required colum value using identifier , this will give me flexibility to reuse this code with similar XML generated by from live application.

I have pasted code below so far I am using to test scenario but with no luck.
Any help and guidance is much appreciate.

```
<ddsml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2005/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/gpm/include/ddsml.xsd">
<server>
<name>AAQ-MMM-Server</name>
<version>YOTV1R14</version>
<functionality>3008</functionality>
<platform>y/OS</platform>
</server>
<report>
<metric id="BPB">
<description>BPB (Central Processor Complex)</description>
<format>report</format>
<numcols>31</numcols>
</metric>
<resource>
<reslabel>,GAQ1,MVS_IMAGE</reslabel>
<restype>MVS_IMAGE</restype>
<reslabelurl>,GAQ1,MVS_IMAGE</reslabelurl>
</resource>
<time-data>
<local-start>20010101155200</local-start>
<local-end>20140708155300</local-end>
<utc-start>20140708055200</utc-start>
<utc-end>20140708055300</utc-end>
<local-prev>20140708155130</local-prev>
<local-next>20140708155330</local-next>
<display-start locale="en-us">01/01/2001 15:52:00</display-start>
<display-end locale="en-us">01/01/2001 15:53:00</display-end>
<gatherer-interval unit="seconds">60</gatherer-interval>
<data-range unit="seconds">60</data-range>
</time-data>
<caption><var><name>BPBHPNAM</name><value>TH7</value></var><var><name>BPBHMOD</name><value>2817</value></var><var><name>BPBHMDL</name><value>713</value></var><var><name>BPBHCMSU</name><value>1473</value></var><var><name>BPBHWF</name><value>80.0</value></var><var><name>BPBHLMSU</name><value>61</value></var><var><name>BPBHGNAM</name><value>N/A</value></var><var><name>BPBHIMSU</name><value>1133</value></var><var><name>BPBHCAP</name><value>0.0</value></var><var><name>BPBHLMAX</name><value>390</value></var><var><name>BPBHGLIM</name><value>N/A</value></var><var><name>BPBHGL4H</name><value></value></var><var><name>BPBHRMSU</name><value>14400</value></var><var><name>BPBHRGRP</name><value>N/A</value></var><var><name>BPBHGAUN</name><value>N/A</value></var><var><name>BPBHCPU</name><value>00000000000FC826</value></var><var><name>BPBHCPNO</name><value>13</value></var><var><name>BPBHICNO</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHIFAN</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHYCFN</name><value>4</value></var><var><name>BPBHIFLN</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHSUPN</name><value>13</value></var><var><name>BPBHPANO</name><value>16</value></var><var><name>BPBHWAIT</name><value>NO</value></var><var><name>BPBHPMSU</name><value>3</value></var><var><name>BPBHDEDC</name><value>3</value></var><var><name>BPBHDEDA</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHDEDI</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHSHRC</name><value>10</value></var><var><name>BPBHSHRA</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHSHRI</name><value>13</value></var><var><name>BPBHVCPU</name><value>NO</value></var><var><name>BPBHWMGT</name><value>YES</value></var><var><name>BPBHCCAI</name><value>100</value></var><var><name>BPBHCCCR</name><value>0</value></var><var><name>BPBHCUTL</name><value>44.2</value></var><var><name>BPBHAUTL</name><value>0.0</value></var><var><name>BPBHUUTL</name><value>12.7</value></var><var><name>BPBHLUTL</name><value>0.0</value></var><var><name>BPBHFUTL</name><value>0.0</value></var></caption><row refno="1"><col>*DP</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>52.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col>1.8</col> <col>33.8</col> <col>35.5</col> <col>CS</col> <col>49</col> <col>3</col> <col>988</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="2"><col>THB</col> <col>0</col> <col>0</col> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>CP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>20</col> <col>10.1</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>30720</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="3"><col>THC</col> <col>0</col> <col>119</col> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>52.3</col> <col>52.4</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>8.1</col> <col>8.1</col> <col>CP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>12</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>AZZ1</col> <col>SYPLX2S</col> <col>12</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>75776</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="4"><col>THF</col> <col>0</col> <col>1</col> <col>NO</col> <col>1.0</col> <col>0.8</col> <col>0.8</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.1</col> <col>0.1</col> <col>CP</col> <col>1</col> <col>0</col> <col>6</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>16384</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="5"><col>TH1</col> <col>0</col> <col>100</col> <col>NO</col> <col>8.0</col> <col>10.8</col> <col>11.0</col> <col>0.2</col> <col>6.6</col> <col>6.8</col> <col>CP</col> <col>8</col> <col>0</col> <col>274</col> <col>34.6</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>AAQ1</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>330</col> <col>145</col> <col>620</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>294912</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="6"><col>TH11</col> <col>0</col> <col>9</col> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>4.0</col> <col>4.1</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.6</col> <col>0.6</col> <col>CP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>4</col> <col>4.0</col> <col>0</col> <col>1</col> <col>1</col> <col>TBI1</col> <col>SYPLX2I</col> <col>4</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>16384</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="7"><col>TH2</col> <col>0</col> <col>106</col> <col>NO</col> <col>8.0</col> <col>11.4</col> <col>11.7</col> <col>0.2</col> <col>7.0</col> <col>7.2</col> <col>CP</col> <col>8</col> <col>0</col> <col>386</col> <col>48.8</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>AAQ3</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>330</col> <col>145</col> <col>620</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>294912</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="8"><col>TH3</col> <col>0</col> <col>42</col> <col>NO</col> <col>4.0</col> <col>9.2</col> <col>9.3</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>2.8</col> <col>2.9</col> <col>CP</col> <col>4</col> <col>0</col> <col>165</col> <col>41.7</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>AAQ5</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>165</col> <col>60</col> <col>165</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>131072</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="9"><col>TH4</col> <col>0</col> <col>0</col> <col>NO</col> <col>3.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>CP</col> <col>0</col> <col>3</col> <col>0</col> <col>100</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>256</col> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="10"><col>TH6</col> <col>0</col> <col>4</col> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>1.7</col> <col>1.7</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.3</col> <col>0.3</col> <col>CP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>30</col> <col>30.3</col> <col>0</col> <col>1</col> <col>1</col> <col>GAQL</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>30</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>4096</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="11"><col>TH7</col> <col>0</col> <col>38</col> <col>NO</col> <col>8.0</col> <col>4.2</col> <col>4.2</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>2.6</col> <col>2.6</col> <col>CP</col> <col>8</col> <col>0</col> <col>56</col> <col>7.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>GAQ1</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>37</col> <col>15</col> <col>70</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>294912</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="12"><col>TH8</col> <col>0</col> <col>18</col> <col>NO</col> <col>8.0</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>1.2</col> <col>1.3</col> <col>CP</col> <col>8</col> <col>0</col> <col>18</col> <col>2.2</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>GAQ3</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>37</col> <col>15</col> <col>70</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>294912</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="13"><col>TH9</col> <col>0</col> <col>63</col> <col>NO</col> <col>4.0</col> <col>13.7</col> <col>13.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>4.2</col> <col>4.3</col> <col>CP</col> <col>4</col> <col>0</col> <col>17</col> <col>4.3</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>GAQ5</col> <col>SPXMY2X</col> <col>17</col> <col>6</col> <col>17</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>196608</col> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="14"><col>PHYSICAL</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>1.2</col> <col/> <col>1.5</col> <col>CY</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>0</col> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="15"><col></col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="16"><col>*YCFPOOL</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>4.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>IS</col> <col>0</col> <col>4</col> <col>0</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="17"><col>THA</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>IP</col> <col>0</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="18"><col>TH5</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>IP</col> <col>0</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="19"><col>PHYSICAL</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col>IY</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="20"><col></col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="21"><col>*YCF</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>4.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>FS</col> <col>0</col> <col>4</col> <col>0</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="22"><col>THA</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>FP</col> <col>0</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>100</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="23"><col>TH5</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>99.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>50.0</col> <col>FP</col> <col>0</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>100</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="24"><col>PHYSICAL</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col/> <col>0.0</col> <col>FY</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="25"><col></col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="26"><col>*KPP</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>40.0</col> <col/> <col/> <col>0.4</col> <col>12.6</col> <col>13.0</col> <col>US</col> <col>40</col> <col>0</col> <col>988</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<row refno="27"><col>THB</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>UP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>21</col> <col>13.8</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="28"><col>THC</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>1.4</col> <col>1.5</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.2</col> <col>0.2</col> <col>UP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>12</col> <col>7.8</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="29"><col>TH1</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>9.9</col> <col>10.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>4.6</col> <col>4.6</col> <col>UP</col> <col>6</col> <col>0</col> <col>342</col> <col>75.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="30"><col>TH11</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>2.0</col> <col>0.1</col> <col>0.2</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>UP</col> <col>2</col> <col>0</col> <col>4</col> <col>5.2</col> <col>0</col> <col>1</col> <col>1</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="31"><col>TH2</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>11.6</col> <col>11.7</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>5.4</col> <col>5.4</col> <col>UP</col> <col>6</col> <col>0</col> <col>342</col> <col>75.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="32"><col>TH3</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>5.0</col> <col>4.4</col> <col>4.4</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>1.7</col> <col>1.7</col> <col>UP</col> <col>5</col> <col>0</col> <col>171</col> <col>45.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="33"><col>TH7</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>0.1</col> <col>0.1</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>UP</col> <col>6</col> <col>0</col> <col>32</col> <col>7.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="34"><col>TH8</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>6.0</col> <col>0.9</col> <col>0.9</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.4</col> <col>0.4</col> <col>UP</col> <col>6</col> <col>0</col> <col>32</col> <col>7.0</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="35"><col>TH9</col> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col>5.0</col> <col>0.7</col> <col>0.7</col> <col>0.0</col> <col>0.3</col> <col>0.3</col> <col>UP</col> <col>5</col> <col>0</col> <col>32</col> <col>8.4</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col>N/A</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>NO</col> <col/></row>
<row refno="36"><col>PHYSICAL</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col>0.3</col> <col/> <col>0.3</col> <col>UY</col> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/> <col/></row>
<column-headers> <col type="T">BPBPPNAM</col> <col type="N">BPBPDMSU</col> <col type="N">BPBPAMSU</col> <col type="T">BPBPCAPD</col> <col type="N">BPBPLPNO</col> <col type="N">BPBPLEFU</col> <col type="N">BPBPLTOU</col> <col type="N">BPBPPLMU</col> <col type="N">BPBPPEFU</col> <col type="N">BPBPPTOU</col> <col type="T">BPBPIND</col> <col type="N">BPBPLPND</col> <col type="N">BPBPDEDP</col> <col type="N">BPBPWGHT</col> <col type="N">BPBPLPSH</col> <col type="T">BPBPVCMH</col> <col type="T">BPBPVCMM</col> <col type="T">BPBPVCML</col> <col type="T">BPBPOSNM</col> <col type="T">BPBPLPCN</col> <col type="N">BPBPLCIW</col> <col type="N">BPBPLCMW</col> <col type="N">BPBPLCXW</col> <col type="N">BPBPCGNM</col> <col type="N">BPBPCGLT</col> <col type="N">BPBPCGEM</col> <col type="N">BPBPCGEX</col> <col type="N">BPBPCSMB</col> <col type="N">BPBPUPID</col> <col type="T">BPBPCAPI</col> <col type="N">BPBPHWCC</col> </column-headers>
</report>
</ddsml>






/* Code */
Sub FetchLiveData()

'Declaration section
Dim CPCxmlDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument

Dim strErrText As String
Dim xmlPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

Dim xresult As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xentry As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

'Initialization
col = 1
row = 1


Set CPCxmlDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
CPCxmlDom.async = False
CPCxmlDom.validateOnParse = False

 If Not CPCxmlDom.LoadXML("C:TestCPC.xml") Then
 ' The document failed to load.

   ' Obtain the ParseError object and format
   Set xmlPE = CPCxmlDom.parseError
   With xmlPE
      strErrText = "Your XML Document failed to load" & _
        "due the following error." & vbCrLf & _
        "Error #: " & .ErrorCode & ": " & xmlPE.reason & _
        "Line #: " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
        "Line Position: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
        "Position In File: " & .filepos & vbCrLf & _
        "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & _
        "Document URL: " & .URL
    End With
    MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation
        Set xmlPE = Nothing
 Else

    Set xresult = CPCxmlDom.DocumentElement
    Set xentry = xresult.FirstChild

    For Each xentry In xresult.ChildNodes

            For Each xChild In xentry.ChildNodes

                MsgBox xChild.BaseName & " " & xChild.Text
            row = row + 1
            'col = col + 1

            Next xChild
    'row = row + 1
    col = col + 1
    Next xentry

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: post your code and ask specific questions about it... Also, which VB are you using? tag your question properly to attract more people

Comment: Hello NirMH,Thank you for your reply, Updated tag and code with little more explainantion , COuld you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem , Solution is working as required

1. Issue 1 Loading errtor , modified CPCxmlDom.LoadXML  by CPCxmlDom.Load
2. Issue 2 ran the loop For Each xChild In xNode.ChildNodes

   ```
   Select Case xChild.BaseName

       Case "row"
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B" & xlrow).Value = xChild.ChildNodes(0).Text
   end case
   ```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you could import your xsd from Developer -> Source and then import your xml from Developer -> Import, but it doesn't put your col elements in different columns since they all have the same name. You could also look into the FILTERXML formula if you have Excel 2013.
Is XSLT an option for you as well?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>refno col1    col5</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="ddsml/report/row">
                <xsl:value-of select="@refno"/>
                <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="col[1]"/>
                <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="col[5]"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output would be:

```
$ xsltproc serverinfo.xsl serverinfo.xml
refno   col1    col5
1       *DP     52.0
2       THB     2.0
3       THC     2.0
4       THF     1.0
5       TH1     8.0
6       TH11    2.0
7       TH2     8.0
8       TH3     4.0
9       TH4     3.0
10      TH6     2.0
11      TH7     8.0
12      TH8     8.0
13      TH9     4.0
14      PHYSICAL
15
16      *YCFPOOL        4.0
17      THA     2.0
18      TH5     2.0
19      PHYSICAL
20
21      *YCF    4.0
22      THA     2.0
23      TH5     2.0
24      PHYSICAL
25
26      *KPP    40.0
27      THB     2.0
28      THC     2.0
29      TH1     6.0
30      TH11    2.0
31      TH2     6.0
32      TH3     5.0
33      TH7     6.0
34      TH8     6.0
35      TH9     5.0
36      PHYSICAL
```

Comment: Hello Kokkie,Thank you for Reply , I am looking thrugh VB code instead xml import , provided code I have managed so far , Could you please help